# AS3 Shoutcast streaming not working in AIR 3.2

Tags: android, actionscript-3, audio, air, streaming

I'm making a simple mobile radio application using Adobe Flash CS6 and ActionScript 3. The code below works perfectly fine when targeting Flash Player 11.2 but fails for AIR 3.2 for iOS, Android and desktop. No sound can be heard but no errors occur either.

```
var channel:SoundChannel;
var sound:Sound = new Sound();

sound.load(new URLRequest("http://groove.wavestreamer.com:9579/"));

channel = sound.play();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put true after your sound.load e.g.

```
     sound = new Sound();
     sound.loadSound ("http://groove.wavestreamer.com:9579/;",true);
```

also check out [this](http://www.wavestreaming.com/player/free-shoutcast-flash-player/?)